# Not getting any output when trying to convert letters in a message to numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a program where the user inputs a message and the program converts it into numbers (eg a=1, b=2, etc). However, I don't get any output! Any help would be appreciated. My code is below.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*;


public class AllRand25 {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] letterArray;
    int[] wordArray;
    int l = 0;
    String messageWord;
    char messageChar;

    letterArray = new int[26];
    int[] messageArray = new int[10];

    int y = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter your message");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = scanner.nextLine();

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        messageWord = scanner.next(message);

        l = messageWord.length();
         Scanner charScan = new Scanner(messageWord);

for(int i = 0; i < messageWord.length(); i++){

    messageChar = messageWord.charAt(i);


    if (messageChar == 'a' || messageChar == 'A' || messageChar == 'A') {
        messageArray[y] = 1;

    } else if (messageChar == 'b' || messageChar == 'B') {
        messageArray[y] = 2;
    } else if (messageChar == 'c' || messageChar == 'C') {
        messageArray[y] = 3;
    } else if (messageChar == 'd' || messageChar == 'D') {
        messageArray[y] = 4;
    } else if (messageChar == 'e' || messageChar == 'E') {
        messageArray[y] = 5;
    } else if (messageChar == 'f' || messageChar == 'F') {
        messageArray[y] = 6;
    } else if (messageChar == 'g' || messageChar == 'G') {
        messageArray[y] = 7;
    } else if (messageChar == 'h' || messageChar == 'H') {
        messageArray[y] = 8;
    } else if (messageChar == 'i' || messageChar == 'I') {
        messageArray[y] = 9;
    } else if (messageChar == 'j' || messageChar == 'J') {
        messageArray[y] = 10;
    } else if (messageChar == 'k' || messageChar == 'K') {
        messageArray[y] = 11;
    } else if (messageChar == 'l' || messageChar == 'L') {
        messageArray[y] = 12;
    } else if (messageChar == 'm' || messageChar == 'M') {
        messageArray[y] = 13;
    } else if (messageChar == 'n' || messageChar == 'N') {
        messageArray[y] = 14;
    } else if (messageChar == 'o' || messageChar == 'O') {
        messageArray[y] = 15;
    } else if (messageChar == 'p' || messageChar == 'P') {
        messageArray[y] = 16;
    } else if (messageChar == 'q' || messageChar == 'Q') {
        messageArray[y] = 17;
    } else if (messageChar == 'r' || messageChar == 'R') {
        messageArray[y] = 18;
    } else if (messageChar == 's' || messageChar == 'S') {
        messageArray[y] = 19;
    } else if (messageChar == 't' || messageChar == 'T') {
        messageArray[y] = 20;
    } else if (messageChar == 'u' || messageChar == 'U') {
        messageArray[y] = 21;
    } else if (messageChar == 'v' || messageChar == 'V') {
        messageArray[y] = 22;
    } else if (messageChar == 'w' || messageChar == 'W') {
        messageArray[y] = 23;
    } else if (messageChar == 'x' || messageChar == 'X') {
        messageArray[y] = 24;
    } else if (messageChar == 'y' || messageChar == 'Y') {
        messageArray[y] = 25;
    } else if (messageChar == 'z' || messageChar == 'Z') {
        messageArray[y] = 26;
    } 
    else if (messageChar == ' ') {
        messageArray[y] = 27;
    } 

    y++;
}

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(messageArray[i]);
        }





}
}
```

Comment: You don't get any output? Or you don't get correct output?

Comment: i dont get any output

Comment: Most of those really messy if-statements can be replaced by `messageArray[y] = Character.toLowerCase(messageChar) - 'a' + 1;`

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no, im not getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors. Too many to point out, it's simpler if I show the correct code with comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[] wordArray;
    String messageWord;
    char messageChar;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
    messageWord = scanner.nextLine(); // read once before entering loop

    while (!messageWord.equals("exit")) { // notice the correct condition

        // these two variables should be reset for each word
        int y = 0;
        // and each messageArray should be of the right size            
        int[] messageArray = new int[messageWord.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < messageWord.length(); i++) {
            messageChar = messageWord.charAt(i);
            // *** insert all those if conditions here ***
            y++;
        }

        // this goes inside the main loop
        for (int j = 0; j < messageArray.length; j++)
            System.out.print(messageArray[j] + " ");

        // we have to ask for the next word inside the main loop
        System.out.print("\nEnter your message: ");
        messageWord = scanner.nextLine();

    }

}
```

Notice that to exit the loop, it's better to have a special string that can be used as a condition - I'm using the word `"exit"` for this.

Comment: i get only the letter 0 for each letter, not 1 for a, etc, when i run this

Comment: @ravensgo copy the above, insert the part with the IF conditions where it's marked (I removed it to save a bit of space), and completely overwrite the main method, I assure you that it works.

Comment: OH sorry i didnt see that in the code MY BAD
that works now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The (or at least 'an') error is in this line:

```
messageWord = scanner.next(message);
```

You're specifying `message` as argument. This seems to be wrong as `next(String pattern)` requires a regular expression that must match the next input sequence. Just call the no-arg version of this method!

Answer (score 0):

Right now the problem as I see it isn't that your code doesn't give results, it is that it doesn't ever end. It infinitely runs.

You are going to want to rewrite your entire code for this. I don't think that there are any quick fixes to make this work how you want.

Might I suggest looking into the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) class to help you this this project?

It is a way to use Strings as indexed Arrays instead of as one object. It could make what you are trying to do much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the `while` loop ends even before the `for`-loop that loops through the `messageArray`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason because you don't see anything is because you retrieved the input outside the outer `while()` loop, and completely forget to do anything useful with that.
Try to comment out this line

```
String message = scanner.nextLine();
```

and your program will run (but there still is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so you need to fix that one too).